# why am I getting null reference exception in one feature file using selenium as the same code working fine in another feature file

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

Hi I am new to C# and selenium I am getting error as object reference not set to an instance of an object.My code is

```
    public LoginPage()
        : base()
    {

        PageFactory.InitElements(Driver, this);
    }

    public LoginPage GoTo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ApplicationbaseURL());
        Driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(ApplicationbaseURL());
        try
        {
            if (this.IsCurrentPage() == false)
            {
                throw new WebDriverException("Not on correct Page");

            }
        }
        catch (WebDriverException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught: {0}", ex);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Comment: At which line does the exception occur?

Comment: So which object is it? `Driver`, `Navigate()`, `PageFactory`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't use destructor in your base class!
If you have destructor in your base class it could be invoked whenever, so you get no driver present.